# python: can i access the index of the element when i use map()?

Tags: python

In python we can use

```
map(lambda word: someFunction(element), data)
```

but can i access the index to tell which element is being accessed?

```
map(lambda word: someFunction(word,indexOfcurrentelement), data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can if you enumerate first.

```
map(lambda (index, word): someFunction(word, index), enumerate(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use "lambda" here is one way:

```
x=[50,100,150]

index = []

for i in x:
    indexis=x.index(i)
    index = index+[indexis]

for a, b in zip(index, x):
    print (a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> map(lambda (i, x): [i, x], enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))
[[0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c']]
```

However, when it starts getting complex, personally I prefer to switch to `for`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(sequence):
   # do something with each 'x'
   # 'i' is the index
```